# How to use an awk variable inside an awk variable?

Tags: string, variables, awk

So, I have a code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v ip="10.0.7.1" -v no="8" -v line='#BalancerMember "ajp://" ip ":8009" route=node" no " loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60' '
/ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests/{
print "             " line ORS $0
next
}
1' /tmp/000-site.conf > /tmp/000-site.conf.tmp && mv /tmp/000-site.conf.tmp /tmp/000-site.conf
```

So, I'm unable to use the awk variable `ip` and `no` inside an awk variable `line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the variable `no` and `ip` within the awk script, the easiest is to use these variables as bash variables:

```
ip="10.0.7.1";no="8"; awk -v line="#BalancerMember \"ajp://${ip}:8009\" route=node${no} loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested following in system with GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v val1="test" -v val2=val1 'BEGIN{print val1, val2}'
```

Which is NOT working and giving output as:

```
test val1
```

So in case you want to use multiple variables why don't use them in main `awk` program itself like as follows.(just an example you could apply it on your code too)

```
awk -v val1="test" -v val2="test2" 'BEGIN{print val1, val2,val1}'
```

Simply you could try to break your variables and if someone's values are common in other ones, in spite of mentioning inside `-v` use them in `print` of `awk`.

---

---

Solution 2nd: Or in spite of using `-v` you could mention variables in `BEGIN` section of `awk` and it should work then.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{ip="your_ip";no="8";line="#BalancerMember "ajp"://" ip ":8009 route=node " no " loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60"}
/ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests/{
print "             " line ORS $0
next
}
1' /tmp/000-site.conf > /tmp/000-site.conf.tmp && mv /tmp/000-site.conf.tmp /tmp/000-site.conf
```

Comment: The 2nd solution gives a syntax error: `awk: cmd. line:1:   unterminated string` and 
`awk: cmd. line:1: syntax error`

Comment: @Ashutosh, I edited it now, point here is wrap your text in `"` and keep variable names as names only if you are mentioning them in another variables like `val="test"` `val1="my" val " value."` so `val1` becomes as `my test value.` now.

Comment: Also, I had one more doubt, suppose if I wanted to store the shell variable value in awk variable `ip` and use the same awk variable inside the awk variable `line`. Is this possible.
Btw your answer works like a charm.

Comment: @Ashutosh, using shell variables in `awk` is very common question asked here, use it like `variable="value";awk -v val="$variable" '{print val}'` where `variable` is BASH variable and `val` is `awk` variable.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @RavinderSingh13. Sorry about today, if you felt that I was rude, You are great man!

Comment: @Ashutosh, np at all, keep learning and keep sharing knowledge.